# Is December & January a good time to visit East Malaysia (sabah region, Borneo) for its wildlife?

Tags: southeast-asia, malaysia, borneo

Area: the sabah region in Borneo (Malaysia)

Time: end of December or begining of January

Activity: wildlife (Orangutan Center, Monkey Sanctuary, Turtle Island)

related [Backpacking to East Malaysia, where to start? where to end?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/12850/backpacking-to-east-malaysia-where-to-start-where-to-end)

Comment: OK in what sense? Weather? National Holidays? Wildlife?

Comment: This questions needs to be refined. Borneo has 3 countries on it (Brunei, Indonesia, and Malaysia). It's also the third largest island in the world. Some parts are safe, some aren't (the East); depending on your nationality/religion it might be okay it might not be. If you can't stand rain then it won't be okay. Generally speaking, it's okay though.

Comment: @Gagravarr & Will: I just tried to be more specific, let me know if there is anything else I can do to make my question clearer

Comment: These are many different questions. Diving is a matter of water-visibility and currents (and therefore skill & danger averseness). Hiking is a matter of weather. Animals can be a matter of season. I would at least split diving from hiking.

Comment: @uncovery : narrowed to wildlife

Comment: alright buddies, what's not clear enough now? I've been narrowing my question each time you asked me to... sigh...